# String search

Tags: string, search, forum, title

What is the best way to search strings for something like forum? i seen horrible string search and typically get worse the more strings you use rather then better.

I also may implement a title search so if the way to search title that is better then a body of string i'd love to hear that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) (Java) (or [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)) for full text search.  Lucene is a text-mining API that allows you to index and search documents by title, text, author, etc.  I've used a Ruby port of Lucene (Ferret or [acts_as_ferret](http://rm.jkraemer.net/projects/show/aaf)) to index a specialized mailing list and found that it works very well.

Answer (score 3):

I would in most cases suggest using the "Boyer Moore" string search algorithm.

You can read about it on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

There's also a lot of example code around to look at, if you're not interested in trying to implement it yourself.

If performance isn't important at all, I would agree with using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly by "Forum", but [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) may be a good place to start.

Too general?